# populating items into a Select using jQuery ajax json, php

Tags: php, json, jquery

simple code to populate items into a Select using jQuery ajax json, php
on first menu change it must make ajax call to fruit-varities.php to get a json array and create the second menu
main page

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Load JSON data with jQuery, PHP and MySQL</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.min.css?1319445416"  />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#mark').change(function() {
             $.get("fruit-varities.php",
                {'idcategory' : idc },
                function(data){
                    var select = $('#series').empty();
                    $.each(data.values, function(i,item) {
                        select.append( '<option value="'
                                             + item.fruit_id
                                             + '">'
                                             + item.name
                                             + '</option>' ); 
                    });
                }, "json");
    });
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <select id="mark">
      <option value="">--</option>
      <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <select id="series">
    </select>
    <div id="view">
    </div>
    </form>
    </body></html>
```

and here is fruit-varities.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['idcategory'])){
$item = Array(
    Array
        (
            "fruit_id" => "1",
            "name" => "Apple",
            "variety" => "Red Delicious"
        )

);
}
echo json_encode(item);
?>
```

this is doesn't work at it all don't know why ?
everything seems to be fine for me but i don't know what is the problem

Comment: I have a Red Delicious BMW ;p

Comment: use a browser console ...will see multiple errors..  `idc` is undefined, there is no object `values` in your  response .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "`idc`" variable in your page, but you are using it as an Ajax request parameter's value. It does not metter, what value `'idcategory'` parameter should have (by analyzing your php script), so you could replace `{'idcategory' : idc }` with `{'idcategory' : ''}`.

Comment: i did that but it doesn't populate any data the series select menu still have no data at it all